# wait/notify mechanism for multiple readers in Oracle sql?

Tags: oracle10g

We have multiple processes which read one database table, get available record and work with it. It works fine.

When there is no record in this table each process waits 5 seconds and reads it again.
So, record could idle in the table for 5 seconds which is not good.

What would be recommended solution to eliminate such waiting and proceed immediately when record is created? One solution could be trigger which does something when record created. But this solution requires knowledge of working processes to deliver record to the one of idle processes.

It looks that ideal solution would be when each process starts to read via SQL from something and when record is created one of waiting processes will have it record and other will continue to wait.

Does Oracle 10 provide such or similar mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm) in 10g, which has since been renamed Continuous Query Notification.

I normally like to include an example but it's hard to find a 10g instance these days, and even a short example requires a lot of code.  The process looks complicated, it might be better off to use triggers as you suggested, and deal with the tight coupling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure it helps me. It looks for me like additional mechanism for update notification. Regular trigger can do this. I'm not interested in update counting. My interest is waiting for update and then notify one (worst case - all) waiting query.

So many processes start query and all wait and when there is something to answer then their wait is over and then can proceed (in worst case scenario - compete for this result, but that's another well known scenario).

Comment: It's not possible to have a single query wait for things to change; Oracle queries are always point-in-time and only return results from the moment the query began.  DCN or CQN can however kick off a PL/SQL or JDBC process that will then run the query.